# Variable adds itself for unknown reason

Tags: python

(EDIT #1)

I am new to coding and tried to create an infinite grid and a way to drag/move the grid using the mouse when any mouse button is pressed.

What I am trying to do is take the coordinates of the mouse right before any mouse button is pressed.
Then calculate the difference in coordinates while mouse is being moved in real time from that starting position (without releasing the button).
Then I want to save that difference and use it to move the grid (after mouse button is released).
After that, when I release any mouse button and the grid was successfully moved, I want to then be able to drag it again without resetting the already existing coordinates of the grid.

The problem with all of this is: when any mouse button is held down and is not being released, if moved from its starting point and then stopped at another location than the starting, the variable "CPD" representing the difference between starting and current mouse position adds itself, yet I do not see why that is supposed to be happening. It is an "=" sign and not "+=" nor is itself specified when measuring the difference and the "if" is not triggered at all, only the "else" is!

[SP - Starting position of the mouse (right before left mouse button is pressed). CP - Current position of the mouse. PPD - The previous difference in starting and current mouse position. CPD - Current difference in starting and current mouse position.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFYc3.png)

[This is the continuation of the previous picture (couldn't fit everything in one)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2x43.png)

```py
import time
import mouse

CPD = [0, 0]  # Current difference in the starting and curruent mouse position
PPD = [0, 0]  # Previous difference in the starting and curruent mouse position
CP = [0, 0]  # Current position of the mouse
SP = [0, 0]  # Position of the mouse right before any mouse button is pressed

# the loop (obviously) so it can check again and again so that the difference would be seen in real time.
while True:

    # simply a way to slow down the code to see the difference step by step
    time.sleep(1)

    # Saves the position of the mouse [x, y] and the previous difference in starting and current mouse position until any mouse button is pressed
    if not mouse.is_pressed():
        PPD = CPD
        SP = list(mouse.get_position())

    # Then, if any mouse button is pressed: it finds current mouse's position
    # Then it calculates the difference in starting and current mouse positions for x first and then y after which it stores the result
    else:
        CP = list(mouse.get_position())
        for position in range(2):
            CPD[position] = PPD[position] + CP[position] - SP[position]

    # all the variable results after math
    print(f"Mouse is pressed: {mouse.is_pressed()}\nSP: {SP}\nCP: {CP}\nPPD: {PPD}\nCPD: {CPD}\n")
```

I have tried to figure it out for a very long time and neither could my friend who is decent at coding (I believe). Any ideas?

Comment: I don’t see the bug here. Your code is adding it if the mouse is pressed, and pressing mouse is a boolean: it is pressed until you release it.

Comment: Are you expecting `Previous_Position_Difference = Current_Position_Difference` to make a *copy* of `Current_Position_Difference`?

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: what module do you use? `is_pressed` can gives `True all time when you keep button pressed. It may need to remeber previous value and compare and add only when previous value was False. Some modules may have function to detect when mouse change value from False to True (and from True to False) and run code only once

Comment: module `mouse` has function `on_click(callback)` to execute function `callback()` only once when you press button.

Answer (score 2):

The confusion here for you is - I think - coming from the interpretation of `mouse.is_pressed()`. This function returns you the current state, not a change of state. So throughout the whole time you have the button pressed, it returns True. It is not that, when you first time access this method, it is somehow reset to False again. Only when you release the mouse button again.

That also explains, why it is being added again and again: You have a loop and check for it every 0.1 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

`is_pressed()` gives `True` all time when you keep pressed button.

You would have to remeber previous value and execute code only when previous state is `False` and current state is `True`

Somethink like this

```
import time
import mouse

Current_Position_Difference = [0, 0]
Previous_Position_Difference = [0, 0]
Start_Position = [0, 0]

previous_state = False

while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    
    current_state = mouse.is_pressed()
    
    if  current_state is False:
        Previous_Position_Difference = Current_Position_Difference
        Start_Position = list(mouse.get_position())
    else:
        if previous_state is False:
            Current_Position = list(mouse.get_position())
            for position in range(2):
                Current_Position_Difference[position] = Previous_Position_Difference[position] + Current_Position[position] - Start_Position[position]

    previous_state = current_state
    
    print(Current_Position_Difference)
```

---

But `mouse` has also `mouse.on_click(callback)` to run function `callback()` only once when you press button. And `on_click` doesn't need to run in `while`-loop.

I don't know what you try to do in your code so I don't know if this code works the same

```
import time
import mouse

# --- function ---

def my_function():
    print('clicked', mouse.get_position())

    Current_Position = list(mouse.get_position())
    
    for position in range(2):
        Current_Position_Difference[position] = Previous_Position_Difference[position] + Current_Position[position] - Start_Position[position]

# --- main ---

Current_Position_Difference = [0, 0]
Previous_Position_Difference = [0, 0]
Start_Position = [0, 0]

mouse.on_click(my_function)

while True:
    time.sleep(0.01)
    
    Previous_Position_Difference = Current_Position_Difference
    Start_Position = mouse.get_position()

    print(Current_Position_Difference)
```

---

Other modules may have also `on_move(callback)` to run function only when mouse change position.